# Soap Web Service Calls from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, web-services

I'm not entirely sure if this is possible, but does anyone know how, or if you can make calls to a SOAP web service from SQL Server?  Seems like it might be good performance-wise in the area of data sync applications.  I feel like this might be a long shot though.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server - Using CLR integration to consume a Web Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180046/sql-server-using-clr-integration-to-consume-a-web-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to refer to this stackoverflow question: [SQL Server - Using CLR integration to consume a Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180046/sql-server-using-clr-integration-to-consume-a-web-service)

Answer (score 1):

Creating a CLR based call is pretty tedious and not really recommended. why do you want to do this?
maybe we can provide another option.

Comment: I don't think there is another option.  I'm basically looking into it because a client of ours said they wanted to use our web service and they don't know anything of .NET programming, all they know is SQL Server.  I was seeing if it was even possible to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or higher, you can call a Web service by creating a CLR Procedure that does the task.